# can i change the width of image, that put by content in css

Tags: html, css

I am making the round tabs form steps, I have to change image when link is active. It's changing perfectly but the size of changed image is different. What should I do for this?
css:

```css
li.active span.round-tabs.two {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  color: #febe29;
  background: blue !important;
  content: url('../images/round-tap-icons/round-tab-icon-3.png');
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
  <div class="liner"></div>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#home"  title="welcome">
      <span class="round-tabs one" onclick="showtabimg()">
        <img src="images/round-tap-icons/round-tab-icon-1.png" />
        <img src="images/round-tap-icons/round-tab-icon-1-white.png" style="display:none" />
      </span>
    </a>
    <h3>order</h3>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#wallet" data-toggle="tab" title="wallet">
      <span class="round-tabs two">
        <img src="images/round-tap-icons/round-tab-icon-2.png" />
      </span>
    </a> 
    <h3>didgital wallet</h3>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a href="#payment" data-toggle="tab" title="payment">
      <span class="round-tabs three">
        <img src="images/round-tap-icons/round-tab-icon-3.png" />
      </span>
    </a>
    <h3>payment</h3>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#confirmation" data-toggle="tab" title="blah blah">
      <span class="round-tabs four">
      <img src="images/round-tap-icons/round-tab-icon-4.png" />
    </span>
    </a>
    <h3>confirmation</h3> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

These are both image link active or link unactive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: consider using js with onhover or onclick event

Comment: ok thanks for you suggestion

Comment: I am struggling to understand the question. You may wish to consider revising your post for grammar and formatting.

Do you mean that you wish to ensure that the images remain the same size?

Comment: I'm feeling the same as @PhilipAdler although grammar isn't that bad... You are not telling us what you want to acheive as the final result, so it is hard for us to help you acheive it...

Comment: @ShubhamShrivastava can you share a plunkr with an example, also can you explain the requirements even better?

Comment: Sorry sir i have no rights to share code , but i am using this type of template 
  templatehttps://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/content-in-bootstrap-tabs, only i have to change inner  icon of round tabs onclick. right now its chaging only background color when click

Comment: Based on your question you have asked, will you try using this in your css: background-size:cover;

Comment: @ShubhamShrivastava The code you shared is about enough for us... But we need to know what you want in the end! You actually do not ask any quesiton

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with multiple images of different sizes in a defined size container, you got multiple options:

The first, the most naïve one and often the best is to simply resize them. Because if you do it manually, you'll be able to do it exactly as you want, and when reducing the size of the image you also reduce the size of the file the users will have to load. So better page speeds.

The second is to use the images as a background of the container. This gives you the option to play with the CSS property `background-size` which could help you resize the picture as you would see it fit according to the results you are trying to achieve. You'll certainly want to use the `cover` or `contain` values. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).

The third possibility is to play with the images' CSS width, height and their min-/max- values. Though you will only be able to define either heights or widths if you want to keep the ratio contraints.

Finally, unlike the comments state, I think javascript would be useless on most cases.

EDIT: When using `background-size: cover/contain` it does take most of the container's size. The trick here could be to either have a smaller container inside. Or better yet, since it seems your container only contains the image, you can use `background-clip:padding-box` and use padding to restrain the size of the background image. Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp)

Comment: yeah i also thought to use image as a background but then it will cover full circle

Comment: Here completed a bit... It would have really helped if you told us what you wanted...

Comment: Dear @Salketer I am using This Template https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3354z , I only want to change the inner icon in round tabs on click. In my code i am using the image in place of icons, i know this is possible by jquery, but i want to know that there is any solution for this in css

Comment: There is no way for CSS to act on click.